# Try ti insert dictionary in dictionary return nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I try to insert dictionary into dictionary by passing dictionary as argument into method. I have a one dictionary with keys 0,1,2,...,6 which consist of dictionaries and i try to fetch dictionary with key 0, in new dictionary but new dictionary is nil.

dictionaryWithWeekDays consist of something like this:

```
0 =     {
        clouds = 0;
        deg = 239;
        dt = 1475175600;
        humidity = 76;
        pressure = "993.71";
        speed = "3.24";
        temp =         {
            day = "70.09";
            eve = "74.73";
            max = "76.64";
            min = "51.53";
            morn = "54.66";
            night = "51.53";
        };
        weather =         (
                        {
                description = "light rain";
                icon = 10d;
                id = 500;
                main = Rain;
            }
        );
    };
    1 =     {
        clouds = 12;
        deg = 337;
        dt = 1475607600;
        humidity = 0;
        pressure = "1012.86";
        speed = "3.89";
        temp =         {
            day = "59.59";
            eve = "64.56";
            max = "64.56";
            min = "49.64";
            morn = "49.64";
            night = "54.32";
        };
        weather =         (
                        {
                description = "light rain";
                icon = 10d;
                id = 500;
                main = Rain;
            }
        );
    };
```

I have a for loop because want to pass all keys in method. and i just call my method into loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
        [self addValuesToArrayWithTemp:dictionaryWithWeekDays key:key index:i];
}
```

And here is my **addValuesToArrayWithTemp** :

```
-(void) addValuesToArrayWithTemp:(NSDictionary *)inputDic key:(NSString *)key index:(int)ind {
    NSDictionary *currentDic = [inputDic objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"currentDic = %@", currentDic);
    NSLog(@"key = %@", key);
   ...
   ...
}
```

`(NSDictionary *)inputDic` - is ok it consist all what i pass before, key also alright have @"0" value. but the currentDic is nil. Why?? Maybe i misunderstand something. Thanks for help!

Comment: Before calling `addValues, can you once check if `dictionaryWithWeekDays` for `key` has some value and post here your findings.

Comment: Can you show code how you have generated this dictionary

Comment: Also try this once `[inputDic objectForKey:@0];`

Comment: @prabodhprakash i do as you say 'NSLog(@"dictionary for key = %@", [dictionaryWithWeekDays objectForKey:key]);' but result is null

Comment: @DmitriyBabinskiy Please try once as i have mention in my above comment.

Comment: instead of `NSString`, try using `NSNumber` as you key, i.e `NSNumber* key = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];`

Comment: @NiravD yes of course i can this dictionary is a part of JSON array and i fetch the pice of date from it and after convert array to dictionary. `-(id)dataFromDictionaryDaily:(NSDictionary *)dic {
     NSArray *arrayWithDictionarys = [dic objectForKey:@"list"];
    
    NSDictionary *dictionaryWithWeekDays = [self indexKeyedDictionaryFromArray:arrayWithDictionarys];}`

Comment: @NiravD the conversation method: `- (NSDictionary *) indexKeyedDictionaryFromArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:
     ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
         NSNumber *index = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:idx];
         [mutableDictionary setObject:obj forKey:index];
     }];
    NSDictionary *result = [NSDictionary.alloc initWithDictionary:mutableDictionary];
    return result;
}`

Comment: @NiravD i try as you say and it help but what it is @0 ??

Comment: Your keys are not string, but number :-) The answer below suggest the same thing.

Comment: @prabodhprakash oh man thank you it's help me!!! its works!! You save my time!!

Comment: @NiravD thank you man for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your printout of dictionaryWithWeekDays  is from the debugger. I believe that your keys in dictionaryWithWeekDays are not strings, if they were, the listing should show "0" = instead of 0 =

You want to check what's actually the type of the key value in dictionaryWithWeekDays.

Comment: *if they were, the listing should show "0"* not correct, did you notice the other keys inside his dictionary ? When printing on console if the key contains a space or _ it will be shown inside "", else "" won't be displayed. In this case your answer might be the correct one but the quoted text is not.